# CSS: How to position divs 2 by 2

Tags: css, formatting, html

the trick is that i want div number 3 to be slightly higher in a way that the margin between 1 and 3 is 15 px like 2 and 4.

http://www.tiikoni.com/tis/view/?id=528cedf

The problem is that the size of the div differs with the size of the data from my SQL query, so i don't know what is the size of the div. 
And the divs are obtained in the order 1,2,3,4,5..... 2 by 2 where each one represents an element of my query.
I already divided divs in leftobject, rightobject.

```
.leftobject
{
float:left;
position: relative;
width: 300px;
border-style: outset;
border-width: 3px;
border-color: #EdEDED;
background-color: #FFFFFF;
border-radius: 15px;
margin-bottom: 15px;
}   

.rightobject
{
margin-left: 315px;
position: relative;
width: 300px;
border-style: outset;
border-width: 3px;
border-color: #EdEDED;
background-color: #FFFFFF;
border-radius: 15px;
margin-bottom: 15px;
}
```

I am running a for loop for outputting divs using json if element % 2 = 0 then it's on the left side else it's on the right side.

Thank you.

Comment: Making them fixed size and scaling the contents is not an option?

Comment: no, this way it looks cooler :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can always use `float:right;` in addition to `float:left;`.

```
#wrap div:nth-of-type(odd) {
    float:left;
}
#wrap div:nth-of-type(even) {
    float:right;
}
```

**[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/GZ5zk/)**

Answer (score 0):

You could do something like this:

Here it is in action: http://jsfiddle.net/X9f7a/

adjust your box sizes (and colour) to your liking of course!

**edit:**
If you don't want the boxes to have a fixed height, you can set the min-height to something. This way, it'll expand the box if there is a lot of writing.

**double edit!**
You might want to read our comments! :)

HTML:

```
<div class="wrap">
    <div class="left-side">
        <div class="box-1">
        </div>
        <div class="box-2">
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="right-side">
        <div class="box-3">
        </div>
        <div class="box-4">
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.left-side, .right-side {
    width:80px;
    height:auto;
    background-color:black;
    display:inline-block;
    vertical-align:top;
}

.box-1, .box-2, .box-3, .box-4 {
    width:50px;
    height:50px;
    background-color:red;
    margin-left:auto;
    margin-right:auto;
    margin-top:5px;
    margin-bottom:5px;
}

.box-2 {
    height:80px;
}

.box-3 {
    height:90px;
}
```

Comment: this is awful for what he is trying to attempt

Comment: really? looks pretty spot on to me.

Comment: if he has to pick a `div` to output his `div`'s into based on if they are odd or even, thats a huge unnecessary performance hit... why not just output them all one after the other?

Comment: I don't see how my code gives an unnecessary performance hit, but maybe I'm just not understanding the question.

Comment: from what I understand, he is adding a class to left or right objects. That already on itself is an unnecessary hit. What you are proposing is that he actually adds the `div`'s into left or right container. Thats an even bigger hit :)

Comment: Ah, I see. I'm not sure if that's what he's doing or not! If so, maybe this would be better? [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/X9f7a/4/), This way he wouldn't need to pick a class, just which div to put it in -- left-side or right-side. I was more focused on getting the look he wanted I suppose!

Comment: Slightly... There are some other issues, say, if your screen is small enough, you will get them stacked as 1,3,5,2,4. My solution would still make them as 1,2,3,4,5 if he wants some custom css for small screens

Answer (score 0):

you can not handle div arrangement for such structure only by CSS.

you need JS for that, you can find many plug-in's for creating such structure.

[Here is one of them](http://www.inwebson.com/demo/blocksit-js/demo2/)

Comment: Thanks, it looks good but Giovanni's answer is what i needed.